# Identification of a segmented black insect in France

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

[image]

[image]

Found in the Lot department of southern France.

Comment: I have no idea what it is. Do you have any more information? Like did it move? How? Did it have any features not visible in the photos? I think I see some sort of pincers in one end, did it have legs?

Comment: was it walking?

Comment: Tag add suggest zoology. Entomology means insect (not all arthropods) , so if it is Not an insect then Zoology  could be a broader term to include it.

Comment: Are you sure this is an insect. Did it have 6 legs? (Comment originally fro @Kasper)

Comment: I think I've seen a similar thing in another stackexchange "species-identification" post, and it was a larvae of some dipteran, but I cannot find something like that in
<http://www.dep.wv.gov/wwe/getinvolved/sos/documents/benthic/midatlinverts/diptera.pdf>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is some sort of soldier fly larva (family Stratiomyidae). That would explain lack of legs. There are thousands of species world wide, with both aquatic and terrestrial larvae, so it might be possible to narrow it down a bit more.

Image from [bugguide.net](http://bugguide.net/node/view/561385) for comparison:

[image]

Thanks to @bli for reminding me of dipteran larvae!